# Jquery position element on top of the window

Tags: jquery

I am trying to position an element on top of the viewport window when I call a function but it doesn't seem to work, I think it has to do with syntax errors.

```
function showSidePage() {
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  $('#projectsPage').css("top", window_top_position)
}
```

if I for example do this instead it works, but thats not what I am after.

```
function showSidePage() {
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  $('#projectsPage').css("top", "100px")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the `position` of your element?  It will work with `fixed`

Comment: read my comment on the posted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally try to take another approach. On click/hover or whatever you could add a class to your element `$('#projectsPage').addClass("fixedPos")`

And that class would have the following css attached to it.

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

Once you're done with that, you could simply remove the class by `$('#projectsPage').removeClass("fixedPos")`

Comment: Yes, the problem is that position: fixed doesn't work for me. I am experimenting with a parallax effect and now when I try to position something as fixed it won't work. I am new to a lot things I am working with here so I don't understand were exactly the problem lies

Comment: is `$window` a variable? if not then it should be `$(window)` that's the only problem I see in that code

Comment: ye it is, I even tried using $(window).scrollTop() as a value

Comment: does the new css get added to your element? you can check from the developer tools. if it does get added then I would say it has something to do with your CSS. are you using `transform` ?

Comment: it does get added as "top: 0px;" and I have a transform: skew on the element but even removing that doesn't make a difference

Comment: ok, so that means that you're using `scrollTop()` wrong. Unless your `$window` element has `overflow` to it or some kind of a scrollbar, `scrollTop` will always be zero, because there won't be any scrolling for that specific element. `$(window).scrollTop()` however, measures the scrolling of the entire page

Comment: ohh ye I didn't think of that. Thanks to the parallax effect I should be using scrolltop on the body instead, it works now thanks for the help